# Removing Asterisks and neighbors from a string

Tags: java, beginner, strings, regex

I am going through the CodingBat exercises for Java. I got to [this problem](http://codingbat.com/prob/p139564):

> Return a version of the given string, where for every star (*) in the string the star and the chars immediately to its left and right (if any) are gone. So `"ad"`, `"ab*cd"`, `"ab**cd"`, `"*ead"`, and `"ade*"` all yield `"ad"`.

I decided to solve this using regular expressions. Here is my code:

```
public String starOut(String str){

    String s = " " + str + " "; //Avoiding OOB exceptions.
    String n = ""; //Used for replacements of s.

    if (s.contains("***")) {
        n = s.replaceAll(".[*][*][*].", "");
        s = n;
    }

    if (s.contains("**")) {
        n = s.replaceAll(".[*][*].", "");
        s = n;
    }

    if (s.contains("*")) {          
        n = s.replaceAll(".[*].", "");
    }

    String theOne = n.replaceAll("\\s", ""); //Remove whitespace created by s declaration.
    return theOne;
}
```

My code is inefficient and repetitious, and does not account for situations of a string containing more than three `*` adjacent to each other. I can't help feeling like I'm missing something obvious of regex that would be a beautifully logical solution.

What would be a good solution to ensure my code utilises regex in an efficient and sensical way? Would it be more appropriate to solve this by looping through characters in the original string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regular expressions are the right tool for this sort of problem, and your suspicions that your code is not great, is about right.... there's the `+` operator in regular expressions which will do what you want much more concisely. `+` matches 1-or-more times.

Consider the simple expression:

```
String compact = raw.replaceAll(".?\\*+.?", "");
```

That replaces all something-stars-something patterns with nothing.

Note, this pattern will have the following results:

```
ab*cd     ad
ab***cd   ad
a**b      
ab****    a
```

etc.

The way the expression works is as follows:

Key features of the regex are:

- `\\*+` - `*` is normally a special character. We have to escape it with `\\` to make it a normal `*`. The `+` is a 1-or-many match. What does this mean? It means that the expression `\\*+` will match at least one `*` character, perhaps many of them in a row.
- `.?` this is a non-greedy 0-or-1 match of any character. This requires some explaining. This will match at most 1 character, but, if the overall pattern will fail to match something, then the pattern can be tried again but matching nothing. What it means, is: *"if possible, match 1 character - any character (including `*`)"*

Putting them together, you get an expression that matches any character, if there is one, before an asterisk, as well as the asterisk, and any other asterisks that follow it, and finally any other character, if there is one.

See this in an ideone here: http://ideone.com/6yMSvx

Comment: It won't work with `abc*` which should output `ab` (adding a `?` after each `.` will fix it)

Comment: @ratchetfreak  it will work, because the regex will backtrack, and the last '.' will match the last '*' ... here, in ideone: http://ideone.com/6yMSvx

Comment: check the last line of the output in your ideone...

Comment: @ratchetfreak - but that is surely by design too? (which is why I added that case). There is no character to the right, nothing to replace.

Comment: Meh, Iplugged the code in to the actual challenge, and, you're right, @ratchetfreak - the challenge expects the right/left chars to be optional, not mandatory, like the description suggests. I will update my answer.

Comment: @rolfl Please may you explain each aspect of that regex statement in this specific context? It would really help me understand how it works.

Comment: @alanbuchanan - edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

A nice solution has already been given, but some details may need some more critique.

```
String s = " " + str + " "; //Avoiding OOB exceptions.
```

There won't be any as `String.replaceAll` is safe in this respect.

But you want to ensure that there's something to match, which isn't a bad idea. However,

```
String theOne = n.replaceAll("\\s", ""); //Remove whitespace created by s declaration.
```

removes *all* whitespace, even such contained in the original string. Using `String.trim` would be better, but still wrong. I can't see any simple solution.

---

```
String n = ""; //Used for replacements of s.
```

No... 1. you don't need it. 2. even if you did, there's no reason to define it outside of the `if`s. 3. and there's no reason to initialize it (hey, it's Java, no bugs due to uninitialized locals as the compiler tells you).

```
if (s.contains("***")) {
```

What about four stars?

You don't have to guard the replacing, if there's nothing found, then nothing gets replaced.

```
n = s.replaceAll(".[*][*][*].", "");
s = n;
```

This may be fine for debugging, but in the resulting code there should be just a direct assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression `[\s+\*+]+`, and use it in, for example "*** *RESIDENT * * EVIL***** "

Solution:

"RESIDENT EVIL"

```
 n = s.replaceAll("[\s+\*+]+", "");
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].